# Different result formats when insert postgreSQL function result between JDBC & console

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, bytea

In postgreSQL, I use **pgcrypto** module to call **pgp_sym_encrypt** function (return bytea type) and save the result into a text column:

For example I have **test** table with column **columnA**(text):

```
CREATE EXTENSION pgcrypto;
insert into test (columnA) values (pgp_sym_encrypt('test','test'));
```

If I run in console, the result is similar to (escaped binary):

```
\303\015\004\007\003\002\022\261B\015\376\235\023\010j\3225\001\244l\253\332\026\037\\Q\305\253\365H\264\222\021\233\345\326\036Ma\346vwq\373\201\303\300\000\303\354\327:\017\020\036Q\201\025\210\364%\215$\017\304Y^_&\267
```

If I run in JDBC, the result is similar to (hex format):

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db", "postgres", "postgres");
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        String sql = "insert into test (columnA) values (pgp_sym_encrypt('test','test'))";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
\xc30d040703026859a0885a496bc66bd240018d9cbede4805fc5b733afc706d061ae613600962222f008ab2fc4e99cc1c87841e3929833066ba42697784276c49efa67655a399fa9f77264769a42eb7c85e
```

If I use **pgp_sym_decrypt** to decrypt, both are decrypted fluently, but I wonder why the results are in different formats. If I want the same format, how can I do?

**UPDATE:**
 I know they are escaped format & hext format and can be set as @Vao Tsun answer. But I wonder why, I thought they have to use same default format? Did the JDBC override format? Is there any config for JDBC for this default format or I have to call the set statement in every transaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the matter of your client settings:

```
so=# set bytea_output to escape;
SET    
so=# select '\xc30d040703026859a0885a496bc66bd240018d9cbede4805fc5b733afc706d061ae613600962222f008ab2fc4e99cc1c87841e3929833066ba42697784276c49efa67655a399fa9f77264769a42eb7c85e'::bytea;
                                                                                                          bytea
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \303\015\004\007\003\002hY\240\210ZIk\306k\322@\001\215\234\276\336H\005\374[s:\374pm\006\032\346\023`\011b"/\000\212\262\374N\231\314\034\207\204\0369)\2030f\272Biw\204'lI\357\246vU\243\231\372\237w&Gi\244.\267\310^
(1 row)

Time: 0.487 ms
so=# set bytea_output to hex;
SET
Time: 2.134 ms
so=# select '\xc30d040703026859a0885a496bc66bd240018d9cbede4805fc5b733afc706d061ae613600962222f008ab2fc4e99cc1c87841e3929833066ba42697784276c49efa67655a399fa9f77264769a42eb7c85e'::bytea;
                                                                                bytea
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 \xc30d040703026859a0885a496bc66bd240018d9cbede4805fc5b733afc706d061ae613600962222f008ab2fc4e99cc1c87841e3929833066ba42697784276c49efa67655a399fa9f77264769a42eb7c85e
(1 row)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-BYTEA-OUTPUT

> Sets the output format for values of type bytea. Valid values are hex
>   (the default) and escape (the traditional PostgreSQL format). See
>   Section 8.4 for more information. The bytea type always accepts both
>   formats on input, regardless of this setting.

**update**

You can set this setting per user `alter user vao set bytea_output to hex` or per database or even per cluster, not only for session or transaction. You definitely don't have to run it before every statement if you don't want of course.

Regarding if jdbc has specific setting - I don't know, afaik you can pass client setting in connect string.

Lastly if you change it per user/db, you will need to reconnect for effect. And `SET LOCAL/SESSION` will overcome this parameter at once...

Comment: I wrote in my question is that I know they are escaped format & hext format. I wonder why, I thought they have to use same default format? Did the JDBC override format? Is there any config for JDBC for this default format or I have to call the set statement in every transaction? I have updated my question.